# For loop JS for a calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a calculator which goes through 18 units. I wanted to make my code shorter by using a for loop. I thought something like this would work:

```
var i=0;
    for (i=0;i<=18;i++)
    {
        if (Unit[i] = "P" or Unit[i] == "p")
        {
            UnitTotal[i] = 70;
            SetCookie('UnitAns'[i],UnitAns[i]);
        }
    }
```

This doesn't work what am I doing wrong or what do I need to do differently?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Unit[i] = "P"
> ```

Unless it throws an exception because `Unit` isn't defined, this will always be true. `=` is an assignment, not a comparison.

> ```
> or
> ```

`or` is not a keyword in JavaScript. The OR operator is `||`.